# Best way to Multiply a 2d array with itself

Tags: c, loops, matrix, multidimensional-array

If a 2d array is always symmetric (4x4 for example), is my method the best way to square the array?
From my understanding, nested for loops can be pretty bad for performance, so I was wondering if it's possible to improve my method.

```
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
      for(int k=0; k<row; k++){
        cur_indx = sq_array[i][j];
        rowXrow = arr[i][k];
        row2Xcol = arr[k][j];
        sq_array[i][j] = (rowXrow*row2Xcol) + cur_indx;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes you can use *matrix chain multiplication method*

Comment: @AnkitGupta: Matrix chain multiplication is about finding the best way to associate a chain of multiple array multiplications. Squaring a single matrix does not fall in that category.

Comment: Your nested loops are fine. Unless you have a specific problem with the run-time, let the compiler do its job and worry about optimizing.

Comment: You should probably just write `sq_array[i][j] += arr[i][k] * arr[k][j];` in the inner loop, and let the optimizer deal with the rest.